# How can I add keywords to make my iOS app more searchable?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

iTunes App store:  How can I add keywords to make my iphone app more searchable?
From the edit I can't add keywords.  If I upload a version 2.0, can I modify the keyword search or do I have to create a different name for the app and do version 1.0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can update the keywords when you update the binary, so you'll have to bump the version number and resubmit.  You don't need a new name.